# How to display the World Imagery wayback in a custom Leaflet map

Tags: esri-leaflet, tile-server

I want to use the world imagery wayback as a visual interpretation tool for some analysis. An easy solution is to download all the coordinates I want to check and display them in their application : https://livingatlas.arcgis.com/wayback. Another one would be to get the URL of the tileserver used in my custom application and understand how to select a specific date.

Does anyone know the url of the tileserver and how the queries work? (I assume I just need the date)